# Problema ao resgatar dados de form no angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Tenho um app móvel tenho um `form` que faz um filtro por distritos e concelhos o que acontece e que não esta a resgatar o dados seleccionados em casa `select` o botão accionado nem faz nada.

**Controller**

```
.controller('FiltraEstabelecimentos', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    $scope.BtnFiltraCat= function (campo){
        $http.post("https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_filtra_estabelecimentos.php?distrito=" + campo.distrito + "&concelho=" + campo.concelho + "&categoria=" +$stateParams.catSlug).success(function (data) {
            $scope.filtra_estabelecimentos = data;
        });
    };
})
```

**View**

```
<div ng-controller="FiltraEstabelecimentos">
        <form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <label ng-controller="ListaDistritos" style="border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;" class="item item-input item-select">
                        <div class="input-label">
                            Distrito
                        </div>
                        <select ng-model="campo.distrito">
                            <option ng-repeat="lista_distritos in distritos" value="{{lista_distritos.id}}">{{lista_distritos.titulo}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                    <label ng-controller="ListaConcelhos" style="border-radius: 10px;" class="item item-input item-select">
                        <div class="input-label">
                            Concelho
                        </div>
                        <select style="border-radius: 10px;" ng-model="campo.concelho">
                            <option ng-repeat="lista_concelhos in concelhos" value="{{lista_concelhos.titulo}}">{{lista_concelhos.titulo}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
                <button type="submit" ng-click="BtnFiltraCat(campo);" style="background-color: #CA5B60; border:#CA5B60; border-radius: 10px;" class="button button-block button-positive">
                    <i class="ion-search"></i> Pesquisar
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>  
    </div>
```

Comment: Poderia fazer um `console.log(data)` e postar o objeto mostrado?
É provável que o `data` em questão contenha em um dos atributos o resultado do request.

Comment: Se tirar os campos que resgato dos select e deixar so a categoria consigo o botao funciona e consigo resgastar a categoria se os tiver la o botao nem funciona

Comment: Não se passa `$scope` como parâmetro no método, o `$scope` pertence ao controller.

Comment: Entao como faco ?

Comment: o scope é o this do controller.

Comment: Sim mas entao como faco nao estou a perceber

Comment: só remove ele do parâmetro do controller e veja se funcionou.

Comment: Removi ficou assim `BtnFiltraCat= function (campo){ }` e nao funciona

Comment: Não precisa remover a variável $scope. do seu método `$scope.BtnFiltraCat = function(){ ... }`. Você até pode passar o scope no controller, mas acredito que não precise. Porém o problema é que você tem que pegar $scope.campo.distrito no seu controller.

Comment: Eu vou dar uma resposta, e depois vc testa, blz.

Comment: ok fico aguardar

Comment: Publiquei lá, veja se rolou.

Comment: Testei mas nao lista nem os distritos nem os concelhos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro crie um serviço:
**OBS:** Pelo que notei, você enviou a url passando parâmetros via get e não post. Por isso, defini como um método *get*.

```
//inicio do serviço
.factory('FiltroEstabelecimentos', ['$http',
            function ($http) {
              //construtor do serviço
              function FiltroEstabelecimentos() {
                var self = this;
                   //método que recebe os parâmetros para retornar a requisição em um promise
                    self.getEstabelecimentos = function(params) {

                          var promise;
                          var distrito = params.distrito;
                          var concelho = params.concelho;
                          var categoria = params.categoria;
                          var url = 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_filtra_estabelecimentos.php?distrito=' + distrito + '&concelho=' + concelho + '&categoria=' + categoria;
                          //método get
                          promise = $http.get(url);
                          //retorno da coleção
                          return promise;

              };
           } //instancia o serviço, permitindo chamar seus métodos no controller
              return new FiltroEstabelecimentos();
}])
.factory('AllEstabelecimentos', ['$http',
            function ($http) {
              //construtor do serviço
              function AllEstabelecimentos() {
                var self = this;
                   //método que recebe os parâmetros para retornar a requisição em um promise
                    self.getAllEstabelecimentos = function() {
                          var promise;
                          var url = 'https://www.sabeonde.pt/api/api_filtra_estabelecimentos.php?all';
                          //método get
                          promise = $http.get(url);
                          //retorno da coleção completa
                          return promise;
              };
           } //instancia o serviço, permitindo chamar seus métodos no controller
              return new AllEstabelecimentos();
}]);
```

Depois no seu controller, use o serviço criado:

```
       //inicia o controller
        .controller('FiltraEstabelecimentos', ['$scope','$http','$stateParams', 'FiltraEstabelecimentos', 
              function($scope, $http, $stateParams, FiltraEstabelecimentos, AllEstabelecimentos) {
                  /* injeta o serviço que traz todos
                     os estabelecimentos 
                     (OBS: método que trás todos os dados,
                      sem passar parâmetros) */
                  $scope.campo = AllEstabelecimentos.getAllEstabelecimentos();
                  $scope.filtra_estabelecimentos = [];

                  $scope.$watch('distrito',function(newVal, oldVal) {
                        $scope.campo.distrito = newVal;
                  },true);
                  $scope.$watch('conselho',function(newVal, oldVal) {
                        $scope.campo.concelho = newVal;
                  },true);

                  $scope.BtnFiltraCat = function () {
                          if ($scope.campo.distrito != null && $scope.campo.concelho != null && angular.isDefined($stateParams.catSlug)) {
                              var data = {
                                           distrito:$scope.campo.distrito,
                                           concelho:$scope.campo.concelho,
                                           categoria:$stateParams.catSlug
                                         };
                              $scope.filtra_estabelecimentos = FiltraEstabelecimentos.getEstabelecimentos(data);  
                          }
                  };
}]);
```

Na sua view, eu refatorei afim de separar melhor, já que está usando 3 controllers, para não confundir a procedência do método e seu respectivo controle:

```
  <div ng-controller="FiltraEstabelecimentos as ctrl1">
            <form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <label ng-controller="ListaDistritos as ctrl2" style="border-radius: 10px; margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;" class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Distrito
                            </div>
                            <select ng-model="distrito">
                                <option ng-repeat="lista_distritos in ctrl2.distritos" value="{{lista_distritos.id}}">{{lista_distritos.titulo}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                        <label ng-controller="ListaConcelhos as ctrl3" style="border-radius: 10px;" class="item item-input item-select">
                            <div class="input-label">
                                Concelho
                            </div>
                            <select style="border-radius: 10px;" ng-model="concelho">
                                <option ng-repeat="lista_concelhos in ctrl3.concelhos" value="{{lista_concelhos.titulo}}">{{lista_concelhos.titulo}}</option>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="margin:0px 10px 0px 10px;">
                    <button type="submit" ng-click="ctrl1.BtnFiltraCat();" style="background-color: #CA5B60; border:#CA5B60; border-radius: 10px;" class="button button-block button-positive">
                        <i class="ion-search"></i> Pesquisar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>  
        </div>
```

Comment: Da este erro no console `"Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: FiltraEstabelecimentosProvider <- FiltraEstabelecimentos <- FiltraEstabelecimentos`

Comment: Não esqueça de colocar o serviço no rodapé do seu layout. Eu acabei de reeditar, qualquer erro é bom revisar, porque eu não testei... eu fiz na raça.

Comment: nao lista nem os distritos nem os concelhos

Comment: serviços vem antes do controller.

Comment: sim e esta antes

Comment: cara, vc está querendo listar, mas precisa enviar um parâmetro para isso, onde vc seta os parãmetros?

Comment: em dois controllers que tenho

Comment: Primeiro você tem que enviar a url completa, para depois filtrar.

Comment: O serviço está correto, ele irá funcionar assim que vc enviar os parâmetros, porém a onde está null, tem q ser a sua injeção de dados `$scope.campo = {
                            distrito:null,
                            concelho:null
                          };`

Comment: Basicamente, seria esse seu outro serviço.

Comment: Ok vou testar entao

Comment: Para listar não é preciso de um filtro, basta colocar o retorno direto de uma coleção, é uma url única, agora se pretende filtrar seus dados, então, tem que fazer o get, ou post dos dados.

Comment: Grande tu já testou também se a api que você está tentando acessar estar retornando valores, o que pode estar acontecendo é isso, pega a url que você está utilizando e testa no navegar, ele deve retornar algo diferente de null

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde grande, tenta tirar o ponto e vírgula do ng-click e no options do select usa o ng-options ao invés de ng-repeat. E você também colocou o `<label ng-controller="ListaConcelhos"...` esse controller como controlador da variável `campo` seria interessante que esses controllers internos fossem funções dentro do controller `FiltraEstabelecimentos`, assim ele reconhece todo corpo da tua view. Por que quando você declara controllers e usa variáveis dentro deles essa variável será tratada por aquele controller e não por outros.

Um exemplo básico do ng-options:

index.html (não precisa de nenhum arquivo para baixado)

```
<html ng-app="teste">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" >
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7 /angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>

<title>teste</title>
</head>

<body>
<nav ng-controller="controllerTeste">
    <div>
        <div>
            <select ng-model="campo" ng-options="lista_distritos.nome for lista_distritos in distritos" ng-change="mostrar()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('teste',[]).controller('controllerTeste', function($scope, $http){
$scope.distritos = [{
        nome : 'teste',
        cod : 1
    },{
        nome : 'teste2',
        cod : 2
    },{
        nome : 'teste3',
        cod : 3
    }];
$scope.mostrar = function(){
    alert($scope.campo.nome);
};


});
```

Comment: com o ng-options  nao me lista o dados

Comment: Como você está utilizando ng-options, seria mais ou menos assim

    <select ng-model="campo.distrito" ng-options = "lista_distritos.nome in lista_distritos for distritos">

Comment: Não da nao mostra nada pode fazer um exemplo de codigo basedado no que tenho

Comment: Pronto grande coloquei na resposta um exemplo básico do ng-options